# Short-circuited temporary lifetime

Tags: c++

Imagine that we have a short-circuited boolean expression, for example,

```
f(g() && std::string().size() == 0);
```

I'm thinking about the lifetime of the `std::string` temporary. Normally, the compiler destructs temporaries at the end of the full-expression. But in this case, that's not appropriate because it doesn't know whether or not `g()` returned true. So I wanted to know how compilers typically handle this situation. Do they store a variable telling them whether or not to issue the destructor call? Or does the Standard permit them to destruct the temporary early?

Comment: I'm fairly certain the standard doesn't even let the temporary be created if `g()` doesn't return true.  (`&&` forms a sequence point.)

Comment: Yes, that's the *problem* to which I refer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&&` short-circuits, so the `std::string().size()` will only ever be evaluated (at all) if `g()` returned true. IOW, if `g()` didn't return true, there's no concern with the timing of destroying the temporary string -- because it'll never be created in the first place.

For example, given code like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

bool g() { return rand() & 1 == 0; }

void f(bool val) {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << val;
}

int main(){
    f(g() && std::string().size() == 0);
}
```

VC++ generates code that uses a temporary variable `$T1` that tracks whether the temporary was generated, and destroys the temporary only if `$T1` is true, so the sequence looks something like this:

```
    int $T1 = 0
    call g()
    if (retval == 0)
        goto $LN3

    call std::string::string()
    $T1 = true;
    call temp_string.size();
    if (retval != 0)
        goto $LN3

    $TV74 = 1
    goto $LN4    

$LN3 :
    $TV74 = 0
$LN4 :
     call f($TV74);

    if ($T1 == 0)
        goto $LN7

    call std::string::~string();

$LN7:
    return 0;
```

I've left out *some* irrelevant details in translating back from the assembly language to this pseudo-code, but retained the original flow and similar enough names that it's pretty easy to compare them to the original if you want.

Comment: Yes, but since you don't know whether or not `g()` returns true, you do have a problem, because when `f` has returned and it's time to clean up, you don't know statically whether or not the temporary was created.

Comment: Were i writing a compiler, i'd generate code somewhat equivalent to `auto temp = g(); if (temp) { temp = (std::string().size() == 0); } f(temp);`.

Comment: @cHao: Which leads to destructing the temporary early.

Comment: @DeadMG: I've edited the answer to show (in detail) how one compiler handles this. Although details would undoubtedly vary, I'd expect most others do roughly similar things.